# extract website meta data from url

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simulate the link posting behaviour like that of facebook or linkedin. i.e. when i post a link the title, thumbnail and other information are dynamically generated.
Is there some way to do that using jquery?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin could be of some use:

[JQuery Metadata Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata)

Comment: If you downvoted this, it would be nice to read an explanation as to why in the comments so that I can improve future answers. Thanks.